# error when url contains 'php' character at the end

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when path contains 'php' character at the end of url.

Example: `<a href="{{route('tags', ['tag' => 'php', 'sortby' => 'frequent'])}}">PHP</a>;`

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('tags/{tag}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@getTag')->name('tags');
```

The problem does not appear when i run with command `php artisan serve` under my local, but only when i do it on server. it is understanding this is a file with a php extension rather than a string and displays the error "File not found". How can I setup to route see my url as a string, not a php file. The image show log here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0VuG.png)

Comment: You've asked the same question before, didn't you?

Comment: @GertB. so it would seem

Comment: yes, have not got answer yet. so I ask again.

Comment: Do I need to remove the previous question.? because this respond wasn't suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your controller ? Your route seems working fine.

Comment: other Route is OK. example 
<a href="{{route('tags', ['tag' => 'css', 'sortby' => 'frequent'])}}">CSS</a>;